# How to remove dishwasher drain plug that got stuck in the garbage disposal

Tags: garbage-disposal

Replacing the disposal one morning before work (1st strike), and while hastily doing this I managed to knock out the dishwasher drain plug, but what I did *not* manage to do was remove the plug from the disposal *before* I installed it and tested it.

Now, I'm pretty sure it's stuck somewhere I cannot see, although I hear it hitting the lugs every time I turn the disposal on.

Is there anyway to remove it?

Comment: Remove unit, dismantle as necessary, salvage plug, check blades, rebuild and refit.

Comment: can you see or feel it inside the chamber? if it's rattling, you should be able to reach it. if the thing won't budge at all and just hums or blows, you need to use the little wrench thingy to reverse the rotation and back out the obstruction. if it's still moving and the plug is plastic, you can probably just grind it away, using a tray or two of ice cubes as lube.

Comment: If there is a woman or kid in the house, they may be able to reach what you can't.  Prove to them the disposal is unplugged or not powered before attempting. (Assuming they have smaller hands than you)

Comment: Just an update: It loosened up on it's own went down the drain. I'm sure some ice and various bone matter over the years helped.

Answer (score 1):

The plug is inside getting chewed up by the disposal blades.  You should be able to just reach in there and feel around for it, and pull it right up out of the sink drain with your fingers.  If you hear it every time you turn on the disposal, it HAS to be down in there.

If the plug is plastic, it probably will not harm the blades, but it could rattle around in there for weeks or even months before it finally gets broken up enough to flush out with the water.  And worse, it will probably break into a few smaller pieces that will not discharge, will all rattle around, and will get jammed between the blades and the housing, causing the disposal to jam.  So you really need to get that little plastic plug out of there.